# Selenium: clicking - div within a div

Tags: html, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have this:

```
<div class="dhx_toolbar_btn def" title="">
<div>Interface</div>
</div>
```

and was wondering how I would get Selenium to click on it, as I tried this:

```
//div[@class='dhx_toolbar_btn def' and contains(., 'Interface')]
```

and this:

```
css=.dhx_toolbar_btn def:contains('Interface')
```

but neither seems to work at all, however it appears to work with other divs that are like this:

```
<td class="td_btn_txt">
<div class="btn_sel_text">Billing Interface</div>
</td>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

**EDIT**
I have also tried these but all don't work, and also don't return any errors:

```
//div[5]/div/div[5]/div[9]
//*[text()='Interface']
//*[normalize-space(text())='Interface']
//*[contains(text(), 'Interface')]
```

**EDIT**
I also just noticed, when I try these last 4 but with a mouseDown instead of a click it does exactly what it is supposed to, (make it look like the mouse is on the item, but not click it), so I am wondering why it would do what it is meant to with mouseDown, but with click it does nothing, not even return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so not exactly the way I wanted it to go, or to make it work but it kinda does:

```
<tr>
<td>waitForElementPresent</td>
<td>//div[@class='dhx_toolbar_btn def' and contains(., 'Interface')]</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>mouseDown</td>
<td>//*[text()='Interface']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>mouseOver</td>
<td>//*[normalize-space(text())='Interface']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>mouseDown</td>
<td>//*[text()='Interface']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>//div[5]/div/div[5]/div[9]</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>mouseOut</td>
<td>//div[5]/div/div[5]/div[9]</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Although I would prefer an easier & simpler method.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS selector option of the [Element Locator](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.html)

Something like this

```
css = "div.dhx_toolbar_btn div"
```

Of course, this would vary depending on how your complete DOM looks like.

Comment: Would I be able to use the DOM idd to click on it?

Comment: If you are setting the Id of an element, you can use it. Check out the Element Locator document, there are many options (including XPath). But choose wisely, DOM parsing is expensive and can slow your tests.

Comment: I looked at the document. Thought I would be able to use this with class:
`xpath=//a[contains(@href,'#id1')]`
but couldn't see how I would specify _'Interface'_ rather than any of the other div's with the same class name.

Comment: Please avoid looking for innerText, your tests will become flaky. The text displayed on screen are subject to changes, without your logic changing. Imagine your site in multiple languages for example. Rather, make your DOM robust and testable, would be my recommendation. In this case, add IDs or Classes to make your DOM testable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the one who made the website, or have access to change it. I am simply meant to use Selenium to make testing the website easier and faster for every new browser that gets released.
Since this _Interface_ has no Class or ID and is just written as `<div>Interface</div>`, how exactly would I use CSS in Selenium to click it?

Comment: In which case, XPath is you only friend. Traverse as much via CSS/Id, and the child via XPath. In this case, something like `//div[@class='dhx_toolbar_btn def']/div`

Comment: I tried this:
`//div[@class='dhx_toolbar_btn def' and contains(., 'Interface')]`
but had no luck with it
I tried what you suggested, and it didn't come back with an error, however the page remained where it was, rather than doing what it was meant to do.

Comment: If you are looking to get the right XPath, I would suggest using a plugin like [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firepath/) that will give you the xpath.

Comment: I did use Firepath to get the exact CSS Path and XPath. The XPath was:
`/html/body/div[5]/div/div[5]/div[9]` and so I did `click` `//div[5]/div/div[5]/div[9]` however nothing happens and no error message appears. I tried to use the CSS but wasn't sure of how to go by it as I got this: `html body.dhtmlx_winviewport div.dhxcont_global_layout_area div#dhxtoolbar_VydhGM1SRkN6.dhx_toolbar_base_dhx_skyblue div.float_left div.dhx_toolbar_btn`

Answer (score 1):

Try the xpath:

```
//div[@class=\"dhx_toolbar_btn def\"]/div
```

That xpath will you the div with text "Interface". If there's more than one div within the div with class "dhx_toolbar_btn" then do

```
//div[@class=\"dhx_toolbar_btn def\"]/div[text()="Interface"]
```

And if you have multiple divs that contain 'Interface' I would construct the Xpath programmatically and pass in the exact text you're looking for, assuming that text is static.

Comment: I tried both the ways you mentioned above and I got the error Invalid xpath.
To clarify, I have multiple divs with the class "_dhx_toolbar_btn def" which have divs within them without classes like the one mentioned above:
`<div class="dhx_toolbar_btn def" title="">
<div>Masterfile</div>
</div>
<div class="dhx_toolbar_btn def" title="">
<div>Interface</div>
</div>`